# What are JAX-WS Interceptors (also known as handlers)?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

What are JAX WS Interceptors? Where do I find info  regarding the same!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JAX-WS interceptors (also called handlers) are used to weave in aspects of the request in a transparent way. Example of this are logging or requests/responses, adding security headers to the message, encryption, compression, etc.  A single interceptor can manipulate either the logical payload (content) of the message or the protocol of the message, but cannot do both.

See [here](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) for the introductory documentation on them.

Comment: Note that, properly speaking, ***interceptors* are not part of JAX-WS**. JAX-WS defines/uses only **handlers**. CXF from Apache, while implementing JAX-WS, also provides *interceptors* as an additional mechanism. So, *interceptors* are not exactly the same than *handlers*.

Answer (score 6):

Handlers are basically similar to filters, but for inboud and output processing of SOAP messages. [Here](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html/) is a quick tutorial I found.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to a Handler in JAX-WS, the RI also provides the Tube concept. It is pretty close to the Filter concept in a Servlet API, as such you can access and manipulate entire in/out packet for a service and a client alike.

I find it more handy for general purposes, like logging of messages and prevalidation of soap headers, etc just because I dont have to attach a @HandlerChain on every web-service. See link.

[Tube based message logging](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#logging)