# adding an annotation to a JAXB binding class from a schema

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

Hi stackoverflow world,

I want to specify in a XSD that a specific element can be used as a XmlRootElement by JAXB.

I know how to add the annotation to the generated class: what I want to do is to specify that a element can be generated as a root element before the code generation.

I use external JAXB customizations (.xjb files).
The purpose is here to not modifying the schemas (as they are defining standards).

Anybody knows how do that?
Thanks!

NJ

Comment: So you want to modify the schema or not (some inconsistency in your question)?

Comment: no, I want to add an additional customization in the .xjb file.

Comment: maybe a beginning of answer http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/jaxb-xjc-code-generation-adding-xmlrootelement-and-joda-datetime

Comment: There is even solution concerning [How to add JAXB annotations at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7958207/267197).

Comment: I may be wrong, but as far as I know an XML root element shall be defined as an XSD global element, otherwise the resulting XML should not be considered as valid (when compared against the corresponding XSD).

Comment: Adding JAXB annotations at runtime may be interesting. However, something like a JAXB customization (in a .xjb file) may be better. Maybe something with the jaxb:class element exists, but I have not find such a thing yet...

Comment: The JAXB plugin Annotate http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin do the thing! However is anyone know how to specify an extension to XJC without ant or maven????

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem solved.

The JAXB plugin Annotate http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin do the job.

Add the following fragment in your jaxb binding file (external binding, i.e. a .xjb file):

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
  <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='GetRecordsType']">
    <annox:annotate>
  <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                 name="GetRecordsType" />
</annox:annotate>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Do not forget to declare the namespaces:

```
<jaxb:bindings 
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox" version="2.1">
 ...
 </jaxb:bindings>
```

And use a ANT or MAVEN task http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/User+Guide to proceed the generation of the sources.

I still search how to specify manually (without an xjc task with ant or maven) the JAXB extensions but it works now. (I have my own ANT script what's why I search to manually call XJC).

The JAXB extension mechanism is very convenient, have a look to JAXB2 Basics:
http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Home

Comment: how to add annotations such as @something({@some("a"),@some("b")}) ?

Comment: Indeed confluence.highsource.org/... seems not available but did you search on the Web? For instance with... google ? ==> https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin