# How do I customize the java annotation generated by JAXB?

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

JAXB generates @XmlAttribute annotations for every attribute. For example, the attribute

```
    <xsd:attribute name="agent_id" use="required" type="xsd:unsignedInt">
    <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Foreign key reference to Agent.agent_id, Included in composite primary key</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

is translated to the annotated java object attribute

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "agent_id", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedInt")
protected long agentId;
```

However, if the attribute does not have an underscore in the name, the name field in the @XmlAttribute is missing (and thus ##default). I would like to customize the JAXB binding such, that also annotations for names without underscore are generated. Any suggestions how this could work?

Thanks!
Johannes

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702559/adding-an-annotation-to-a-jaxb-binding-class-from-a-schema)

Answer (score 1):

You could write an XJC plugin to add this behaviour:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

As far as a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is concerned the result XML will be the same.

Comment: So I will not go far with custom bindings as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)? Then I will stick to my python post-processing scripts. Thank you for your answer!