# Adding annotations to generated classes using jaxb bindings from schema

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations, xjc

I am using xjc to generate classes from schema. I would like to add custom annotations to the generated code using jaxb bindings. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702559/adding-an-annotation-to-a-jaxb-binding-class-from-a-schema). But it was not of much use as I am looking to add annotations like this:

```
 @something({@some("a"),@some("b")})
```

How do I add annotations such as the one mentioned above?