# How to generated extra annotations on JAXB2 generated Java from XSD

Tags: xsd, jaxb, resteasy, jaxb2, jackson2

I have the following type of structures in my XSD's..

[image]

And this is generating code that enumerations that serialize correctly back-and-forth from XML.

Now, those same XML/SOAP services are being implemented as REST using Jackson and RestEASY. It all works correctly with no further additional settings, except for the enumerations which are constrained values that we want to serialize to those generated Java enums. However, the classes are devoid of JSon annotations, causing them serialize and deserialize the string values of the generated enumerations instead.

What I need it to generate the code with @JsonValue and @JsonCreator so that we can process the enumerations based on their assigned values instead...

[image]

How can I modify the JaxB2 generator to have it add add the Json annotations as well? There are several hundred enumerations in the system, so a systemic solution is called for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding an annotation to a JAXB binding class from a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702559/adding-an-annotation-to-a-jaxb-binding-class-from-a-schema)

Comment: See: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin and the linked duplicate.
**Disclaimer**: I'm the author.