# How to create XSD definition in such a way that JAXB created classes from such XSDs will generate xml with empty xml tag if field is null

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xml-deserialization

How to create XSD definition in such a way that JAXB created classes from such XSDs will generate XML with empty XML tag if the field is null.

We can use `nillable=true` but it adds `nil=true` data in generated XML. Generated XML should be with clean empty tag element if an element is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Represent null value as empty element in xml jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366054/represent-null-value-as-empty-element-in-xml-jaxb)

Comment: How to embed @XmlCustomizer behaviour in xsd definition?

Comment: You need to use [Eclipse MOXy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) and `jaxb:bindings`, for example take a look on [adding an annotation to a JAXB binding class from a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702559/adding-an-annotation-to-a-jaxb-binding-class-from-a-schema)