# ObjectMapper for multiple naming strategies

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, objectmapper

I am dealing with a dataset where both underscores and hyphens are being used between tokens in property names:

```
    {
      "id" : "116",
      "priority" : 3,
      "table_id" : 0,
      "hard-timeout" : 0,
      "match" : {
        "ethernet-match" : {
          "ethernet-type" : {
            "type" : 2048
          }
        },
        "ipv4-destination" : "10.0.0.25/32"
      },
      "strict" : false,
      "flow-name" : "port_X_to_8_ip",
      "instructions" : {
        "instruction" : [ {
          "order" : 0,
          "apply-actions" : {
            "action" : [ {
              "order" : 1,
              "output-action" : {
                "max-length" : 60,
                "output-node-connector" : "8"
              }
            } ]
          }
        } ]
      },
```

Notice most elements have hyphens, but a few use underscores, such as `table_id`.

On the Java side, I am using this code to create my mapper:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
...
JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).build();
jsonMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE); // <-- combine this
jsonMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE); // <-- with this?
```

The last two lines are my current crux. I want the naming strategy to work for either `SNAKE_CASE` or `KEBAB_CASE` however I don't see a way to `or` the properties and can't find much on google.

Answer (score 4):

You pick the naming strategy that fits for most properties, then use the [`@JsonProperty()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation to name the ones that don't follow the standard.

In your case, that would be [`PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html#KEBAB_CASE) and `@JsonProperty("table_id")`.

Comment: Well the problem is I am using the XSD file and jaxb Maven modules to generate my beans and xml classes. Is there a way to tell jaxb or incorporate it in my xsd file?

Comment: @E.S. [adding an annotation to a JAXB binding class from a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8702559/5221149)

Comment: I appreciate the link. There are a lot of good hints in that SOF item, however unfortunately, the author links to expired confluence articles, such as this http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin. That said I am playing around with creating a binding.xjb file but I feel I am stabbing in the dark a bit. Is there a more updated documentation on this?