# JAXB ignore fields from processing

Tags: jaxb

I have the following class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Test {

    @XmlTransient
    private String abc;

    @XmlElement
    private String def;

}
```

My question is, I want to use this class to generate two kinds of XMLs

```
1. With <abc>
2. without <abc>
```

I can achieve the second one since I have marked it as transient. Is there any way so that if I mark "abc" as `@XMLElement` and can ignore it while marshalling?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957195/how-to-use-jaxb-annotations-at-runtime

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You may be interested in the `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` extension we have added in EclipseLink 2.5.0.  It allows you to define multiple views on your domain model.  You can try this out today using a nightly build:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Below I'll give an example:

**Test**

The `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` annotation is used to define subsets of the object graph that can be used when marshalling and unmarshalling.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlNamedObjectGraph(
    name="only def",
    attributeNodes = {
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode("def")
    }
)
@XmlRootElement
public class Test {

    private String abc;
    private String def;

    public String getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setAbc(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    public String getDef() {
        return def;
    }

    public void setDef(String def) {
        this.def = def;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The `MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH` can be used to specify which object graph should be marshallled.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setAbc("FOO");
        test.setDef("BAR");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Marshal the Entire Object
        marshaller.marshal(test, System.out);

        // Marshal Only What is Specified in the Object Graph
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "only def");
        marshaller.marshal(test, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  The first time the instance of `Test` is marshalled it contains all the properties and the second time just the `def` property.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <abc>FOO</abc>
   <def>BAR</def>
</test>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <def>BAR</def>
</test>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-partial-models-on.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise, but I cannot use Moxy.. Thanks a lot for your response.