# Viewing SOAP request from Java client

Tags: java, soap

I have built a Java client for an external web service. When I send a request using Eclipse I get a response, but it is not the response I expect. I think I have traced this to one of the fields (a date field), but I can't work out if it is on my side that the conversion is wrong or on theirs, only that the response returns a different date than the one I sent.

How can I see the SOAP request in the xml format that it is sent in to check how the date field is being sent to the external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a Jax-WS interceptor/handler. They are very easy to write. Netbeans actually has great built in support for them. But if you want to write one from scratch, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398362/jaxws-interceptors)

Comment: I can't get netbeans (can't download programs at work). I've written a handler, but don't know how to attach it to the web service. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark. It's pretty easy. If you don't know how to use it just type "wireshark soap" in Google.