# How to wrap (envelop, enclose?) @WebMethod execution in custom annotated class

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

With using of JAX-WS, implemented `@WebMethod` method in `@WebService` class.
Need to do something like this:

**WebService.java:**

```
@WebMethod
@MyWrapper
public Object someWebserviceMethod() ...
```

Here is `MyWrapper` annotation, which must wrap call of `someWebserviceMethod` into another code, where it will be decided whether to execute it or not.   For example, in such way:

**MyWrapperImpl.java:**

```
...
public Object wrapMethodExecution( contextOfCalledWebMethod ) {
    if ( someFlag ) {
        //then contextOfCalledWebMethod called to execute someWebserviceMethod
        //or directly call Method.invoke()
    } else {
        return null; //or error message
    }
```

So `wrapMethodExecution()` needs to be automatically called before the call to any method, annotated with `@MyWrapper`.

Is it possible to perform such pattern by using jax-ws?

I tried to use `WebServiceFeatureAnnotation` but failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are JAX-WS Interceptors (also known as handlers)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398362/what-are-jax-ws-interceptors-also-known-as-handlers)

Comment: think - not, cause WebService.java already has shown architecture, and it seems that using of interceptor will cause to redesign it. 
so i need the solution, where only changes in WebService.java are - to add @MyWrapper anotation where neccessary

Comment: There's no magic annotation for that - your options are: a handler, or [a CDI interceptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html)

Comment: I'm not looking for magic))). 
I hoped, that there are standard instruments in JAX-WS, that give abilities to extend it's functionality by custom annotations (thought - WebServiceFeatureAnnotation was such one). But i failed to find them.